# Coloring the largest weakly connected component in a network

Tags: netlogo

I am basically trying to color the largest weakly connected component. nw:weak-component-clusters is returning a list of all components present in the network. I want to color only the largest one. My code is coloring all of the components.

```
 let clusters nw:weak-component-clusters 
 print length(clusters)
 show clusters
 show sort (clusters)
 foreach clusters [ 
   set color pink
 ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`sort-by`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#sort-by) to sort your list of clusters by descending size and then ask the first one of these to change its color:

```
extensions [nw]

to setup
  clear-all
  create-turtles 100 [
    set color blue
    create-links-with n-of random 3 other turtles
  ]
  repeat 30 [ layout-spring turtles links 0.2 5 1 ]
  let clusters nw:weak-component-clusters 
  ; sort by descending size of cluster:
  let sorted-clusters sort-by [ [c1 c2] -> count c1 > count c2 ] clusters
  ask first sorted-clusters [ set color pink ]  
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much.